Why does graphblas return different results as networkx?
I'm trying to use graphblas algorithms to speed up computation on a big network using Python. Unfortunately, the results returned from graphblas are different from the ones given by network algorithms even for very trivial networks. Here is a minimal working example:
import networkx as nx
import graphblas_algorithms as ga

G = nx.DiGraph([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3)])
nx.in_degree_centrality(G)
{0: 0.0, 1: 0.3333333333333333, 2: 0.6666666666666666, 3: 0.6666666666666666}

GG = ga.Graph.from_networkx(G)
ga.in_degree_centrality(GG)
0   1     2 3
1.0 0.666667  

I can't wrap my head around this. Does somebody have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?
I'm expecting both to return the same results but they obviously aren't.

There seems to be a bug in graphblas, as it's values are wrong.
From the networkx documentation:

The in-degree centrality for a node v is the fraction of nodes its incoming edges are connected to.

Applying this definition to your toy example:
0 : 0/3 = 0 # 0 incident edges, 3 other nodes in the network 
1 : 1/3 = 0.33
2 : 2/3 = 0.66
3 : 2/3 = 0.66

Incidentally, graphblas is giving the correct values for the out-degree centrality (albeit missing all key-value pairs with a value of zero). As the graphblas implementation of degree centrality queries pre-computed node features, it seems likely that the issue originates from a confusion of which pre-computed feature to use for what degree centrality measure ("column_degrees+" vs "row_degrees+").

Hey @paul-brodersen I posted this over on github during the bounty and one of the core dev's responded back just now. Thought i'd mention it so you could make any edits above as needed. https://github.com/python-graphblas/graphblas-algorithms/issues/96#issuecomment-2118815797
